# Convert hex 0xAABBCC to string "AA:BB:CC" using sprintf

Tags: c++, printf, hexdump

I have a hex number `0xaabbcc` which I would like convert and format into a char string as `AA:BB:CC`.

using `sprintf(myStr, %X, 0xaabbcc);` results in `char myStr[] = "AABBCC";`

Is it possible to use `sprintf` or some other function to convert and format `0xaabbcc` to `AA:BB:CC`?

Comment: You will have to write your own function to do the formatting you want. And yes, that function can use `printf()`.

Comment: What you are asking for can't be done in a single operation. Store the number in an integer, then break it up into its individual bytes, and print out each byte in hex with `:` in between each byte

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies.  I will use an additional func to add the ":" token char. I wasn't sure that maybe I missed something with the use of sprintf.  Will post my solution here for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the specifier string with quotes. The [`printf` family](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) receives a `const char*` as the format string. `%x` alone outside of a string means something modulo by x, and will result in compiler error if there's no integer before `%` like in your case

After that just split the bytes you want to print

```
unsigned v = 0xAABBCCU;
sprintf(myStr, "%02X:%02X:%02X", v >> 16, (v >> 8) & 0xFFU, v & 0xFFU); // or
sprintf(myStr, "%02X:%02X:%02X", v >> 16, (uint8_t)(v >> 8), (uint8_t)v);
```

However since you're using C++ it'll be safer to use std::string

```
std::stringstream myStr;
myStr << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
      << std::setw(2) << (v >> 16)
      << std::setw(2) << ((v >> 8) & 0xFFU)
      << std::setw(2) << (v & 0xFFU)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `printf` and you are using GCC (or maybe Clang, but I can't find anything documented) then you can use [printf cusomization](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html).

Frankly @phuclv's answer is probably better.